# What redirect code can solve my duplicate homepage?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I've got a problem with a website, and i don't know which code i must use to solve it.

I've run a crawl test, which results in the following structure:

www.domain.com 
www.domain.com/ (this is a **big** problem, because it's duplicate content)
www.domain.com/category
www.domain.com/category/page
www.domain.com/category2
www.domain.com/category2/page
www.domain.com/category3/subcat4/page
etc.

As you can see, the subpages don't have a trailing slash.
My question is: **What redirect code is the most effective way to solve the duplicate homepage problem?** Taken in account, the subpages don't have (so don't need?) a trailing slash.

Answer (score 4):

You could just force a trailing slash with .htaccess
Something global would look like this (quick untested code)

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

You can ofcourse just specify the root, and not use the (.*).

Answer (score 2):

`www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/` are equal! The browsers have the stupid property to hide the prefix and the suffix of an URL in some cases.

Both Examples will point to `http://www.domain.com/` while Firefox e.g. will show in the default settings only `www.domain.com`. Everything behind the first slash can have but must not a second one.

That means if you have a directory called downloads and the browser requests `http://www.domain.com/downloads` the server will redirect the client to `http://www.domain.com/downloads/`.

But be careful with "virtual" pathes which are used often in search enigne optimised pages. Most times the CMS won't redirect a client from 
`http://www.domain.com/article/welcome/` to `http://www.domain.com/article/welcome` which will produce double content, also just if the CMS won't provide the right `meta` for resolving double content.

Comment: Not true, or at least irrelevant. Google sees the 2 URI's as different, and will add both of them to the index. And mark them as duplicate. see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html

Comment: I was talking about the slash after the domain. Not the slash of a path. I will update my answer.

Comment: yes, but this site responds (or so it is claimed I think) to the `domain` as well as `domain/`. If they are not redirected but serve a 200, it is still a problem.

Comment: I know what you mean, that is a good point, but don't mix up the domain with the path.

Comment: It's not limited to any sub'dir', it works for the root as wel. And the root seems to be the problem here, as that's the one with the double content.

Comment: Now you are confusing me... If we look to the HTTP protocol `GET / HTTP/1.0` would request the root directory. The server would response bad request if you would remove the slash in the request.

Comment: point taken, and I know there is some discussion about validity for this problem for the root of a site, but is a crawler finds links to "/" and "non-/" root of your domain, it might still be counted as double, apart from what the final request may be. As it is a minor fix, I would suggest imagining it to be a valid request. Maybe even just fix it with a canonnical ?

Comment: will you tell me that this two links points to two differnt sites? `<a href="http://example.com">example.com</a>` and `<a href="http://example.com/">example.com/</a>`

Comment: The problems seems to be that it can be in the google index, not that it is a different site.